# Load high res image in background firefox flicker

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a site that has two types of images (high res and low res). I want to display the low res image first because often it is already preloaded and if not then it is quicker to load.

What I did was I created an img with the src set to the low image url and then created a javascript image with src set to the high image url. I then changed the img's src as soon as the javascript images onLoad function is called. (I haven't posted any code because I wrote it in React and the code is slightly different).

This is working fine on all browsers except firefox. Instead of changing the src smoothly there are a few milliseconds where there is no image displayed and then the high image is displayed. I'm wondering whether there is a fix for this.

Comment: Currently I am thinking if it is a bad idea to just overlap both images and when the high res image is loaded then hide() the low re and show() the high res.

Answer (score 1):

From googling your problem it seems to be a bug in firefox.

The flicker seems to be caused by the time firefox needs to scale the image.

Try to make firefox render the image in the right size by adding it to the DOM with style before swapping your img-src. Maybe offscreen like `left:-10000px;` or even in the right position.

Sources:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=705826
https://kylekelly.com/posts/2014/04/08/firefox-flickering.html

Comment: "or even in the right position" - no, because that causes a horizontal scroll bar to appear.  "Standard" position it off the left is usually done as `left: -999em;` - but yours will work fine.

Comment: I tried that but it did not stop the flicker. The worst case when it happens is when the image is already cached and I display the low res image for a very small time until the onLoad function is called and switches the src.

Comment: Are you sure you preload the hires with exactly the same size and style (apart from position)? Alternatively you could try replacing the whole node in the DOM instead of just the `src`-attribute. Or just adding it as a sibling-node with `position:absolute;` as an overlay. -- Replacing the src should be possible though.